# C++ bindings to jGoodies?

Tags: c++, user-interface, gui-designer, jgoodies

Thus far the best C++ UI libraries I've run into are Qt, GTK, and wxWidgets; Are there existing libraries similar to [jGoodies](http://www.jgoodies.com/) or 'better'. I am interested in mature (yet simple) technologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QT is about as good as it gets AFAIK.

Binding a Java toolkit to C++ is a rather convoluted idea since in C++ you usually have a direct interface to the OS widgets. going full circle through Java is guaranteed to have uglier results.